# style="width: 45px !important" in Django not works

Tags: html, css, django

I'm using django to make a web site.

When I render`<img src="{{ board.writer.profile_photo.url }}" width="45px" height="45px" style="width: 45px !important; border-radius: 50%;"/>`
this html, the `style="width: 45px;"` part changes into `style="width: 100%`. I have no idea why this happens.
[screenshot from chrome devtool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZByI9.png)

I'm using python3.8, django 4.0.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Just an observation: width and height attributes should not have a unit specified.

Comment: I just found that a line of javascript was causing this problem...